# F# Recursive Member Function : "How to Define it correctly"

Tags: recursion, f#, member-functions

I it is my understanding that when you define a recursive member function within a type then there is no need to define the function to be recursive. Meaning use of the `rec` keyword.

however when i do this:

```
type hello() = class
  member this.recursion(x) =
      match x with
      |10 -> printfn "%A" x
      |_ -> printfn "%A" x
            recursion(x+1)
end
```

Then i get the error that recursion is not defined.

I have tried `this.recursion` but then i still get a warning saying:

The recursive object reference 'this' is unused. The presence of a recursive object reference adds runtime initialization checks to members in this and derived types. Consider removing this recursive object reference.

So i am wondering what is the correct way to define a recursive member function within a type?

Comment: The warning you're getting is usually issued for _values_, not functions. Are you sure you're getting this warning with the exact code you posted? Or was it for different code that you're not showing us?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, they work when defined as members.
As you already noticed, you're missing the `this` at the call site. It should be:

```
this.recursion(x+1)
```

But this works well, at least for me:

```
type hello() = class
  member this.recursion(x) =
      match x with
      |10 -> printfn "%A" x
      |_ -> printfn "%A" x
        this.recursion(x+1)
end
```

Anyway I would define it internally, as showed in the other answer but inside the method:

```
type hello() = class
  member this.recursion(x) =
    let rec loop x =
      match x with
      |10 -> printfn "%A" x
      |_ -> printfn "%A" x
            loop (x+1)
    loop x
end
```

Comment: Thanks this will make my life way easier in the future!

Answer (score 3):

You can define normal recursive function within the body of your class (it will be private function) and then expose it as member, example:

```
type Hello() =

    let rec recursion x =
        match x with
        | 1 -> printfn "%A" x
        | _ -> printfn "%A" x; recursion (x+1)


    member this.Recursion(x) = recursion x
```

Comment: I think this is a good practice, but I will rather define the ``let rec``  inside the ``member``, as an inner function, no need to be at the type level scope.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question though.